# Portable Way to Get Users Language in C

Tags: c, localization

I've been trying to come up with a way to detect a users language in C so that I can display a translated version of my application without them having to configure the language themself in the settings.

I'm aware of the trick with setlocale(LC_MESSAGES,NULL). However, its not really quite clear how I can use this reliably.

- It does not work on macOS (as it returns the locale of the machines region, rather than the Users configured language setting (ie. if a user has a US Macbook Air, with their GUI's configured primary language Chinese (and rendering all strings in Chinese), setlocale will return "en_US.UTF-8")
- The string returned is not in a standardized format that is easy to parse for the language identifier without a significant amount of platform specific code
- There is many different ways of representing the same language even on the same OS that this string can return (ie. "en-US", "English", "English_United States.1252", ".1252")
- Some results for this do not specify a language at all (ie. "C", or "UTF-8")

Is there any cross platform libraries or other tricks that can be used to get to something standardized like an enumeration per language that could be used in flow control?

I've thought about rolling my own using OS specific functions (like GetUserDefaultUILanguage()), but it seems very error prone, and difficult to test for bugs across the Cartesian product of languages and OSs, so I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: `setlocale(LC_MESSAGES,NULL)` isn't a _trick_.  It's the standard way to set a locale facet.

Comment: It might be instructive to see what common toolkit libraries use.  Have a look at gettext, for instance, or perhaps Qt (there are many others; I just picked ones I've used).

Comment: There is **no** way to get the language that the user prefers to read or speak other than by asking them.  What you can get at programmatically is how the execution environment has been configured, and in particular, this is what locale settings are about.  Very often these two sources will correspond with each other, but that may not always be the case, so you need to decide which one you mean.

Comment: As far as localizing your application's text, the usual approach involves assigning a code to each distinct label / message, and providing a database of some form that maps those codes to text for each supported locale.  There are existing libraries for supporting that kind of thing ([GNU gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/), for example), and you'll find built-in support in at least some application frameworks.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I already have implemented localization on the app side, with user configurable language selection. However, I am just looking at setting up the autodetection based on the users configured language for the operating system. Unfortunately, the application framework I'm using does not feature built in support.

Comment: Automation is just not going to work everywhere. Consider a bilingual (or more) user that has a customer coming in. They now want the display to work for their new customer. What language will  your code select?

Comment: @BoP, The intent would be to display the same one that the OS is displaying its GUI in.

Comment: Pedantically: `setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, NULL)` does not *set* anything, it returns the current locale for the specified category. `setlocal(LC_MESSAGES, "")` sets the user-preferred locale for the specified category ([ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/setlocale), C11 [§7.11.1.1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.11.1.1)).